# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: color_scale.js in a Pyinsttaller bundled Python-Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, pyinstaller

The app works fine, but when trying to run the Pyinstaller bundled .exe file, it gives me the message: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: color_scale.js

This .js file is in ...Lib\site-packages\branca\templates. I've already inserted a corresponding association in the .spec file so Pyinstaller could collect it:

```
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
...
 datas=[(...
...
("C:...\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\templates","templates"),
...
```

Previously, I've had a ValueError: The 'branca' package was not installed in a way that PackageLoader understand, witch I've solved by patching .../site-packages/branca/element.py to use jinja2.FileSystemLoader instead of jinja.PackageLoader when dealing with a frozen application:

```
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    import os
    from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader
    bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS')
    data_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(bundle_dir, 'branca', 'templates'))
    ENV = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(data_dir))
else:
    ENV = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('branca', 'templates'))
```

I'm dealing with Python 3.9.6, Flask 1.1.2, Werkzeug 1.0.1 and Pyinstaller 3.6.

I don't know the relation, but this problem do not occurs in a 32 bit old version of the bunled app.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You should put it in branca/templates I guess, which is ``"C:...\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\templates","branca/templates")``. In addition, you can use ``--collect-data branca`` and see that if it works.

Comment: @gfdsweds nailed it! `"C:...\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\templates","branca\templates")` solved the problem. I've had to to use the FileSystemLoader-PackageLoader patch in all folium scripts for the subsequent issues, but is OK now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

I stumbled across the same error when trying to convert my app.py running with flask file into an executable using pyinstaller. When navigating to 127.0.0.1:5000 (where the application is hosted in my case) after executing the executable there is the *TemplateNotFoundError*. Eventhough the app runs perfectly when just executing the app.py file directly.
It was quite difficult to find out where flask acutally looks for the templates it tries to load. My solution is more a workaround than an actual fix to the problems root. My file structure looks sth like this:

```
main_folder
|- web_app
    |-templates  
    |-app.py
```

And I executed the pyinstaller command while being in the main_folder.

## Find out where Flask looks for templates

When creating the executable from powershell do NOT use the -w option. Passing this option will prevent a cmd window to be opened when running the exe and thus deny the output we are trying to see. In my case the Creation looked something like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile 'web_app/app.py' --paths='C:\Users\nick\file\to\selfwritten\packages\to\load' --collect-data='web_app.templates'
```

Be sure to add any packages which you load "dynamically" e.g. by manipualting sys.path on runtime to the --paths option (according to [When sth. goes wrong- pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html)).

Additionally you have to tell flask that you want to see where it loads the templates from. In Order to do this there is the 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING' option that can be passed to your flask app. In my case I added it to the beginning of my app.py file(third line in following code)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '<your secret key>'
app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING']= True
```

After doing both of these things (Obviously the latter one has to be made before creating the executable) One can execute the exe file created. When doing so you should see a cmd window displaying a similar output like the following:
[I am not yet allowed to add the images in post :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anpNs.png)
For each template it loads there is some output also containing the searchpath which it tries to find the template in. As you can see it is some weird temp path which does not include your templates by default. In your case there should be some line like "no matches" when looking for templates(The screenshot above is taken after fixing the problem). So now the only thing we have to do is to get pyinstaller to add the templates automatically to that temp folder when executing the executable.

## Make pyinstaller create the correct Temp files

After finding out where flask looks for the templates we will have to delete the executable we have created until now(to be sure nothing is cached just delete all files and folders created with pyinstaller(dist, build, the exe file and the spec file)). Now we just have to add the templates folder we want to load to the folder we create the exe from. In my case that is the main_folder which will leave me with the following file structure:

```
main_folder
|- templates
|- web_app 
    |-app.py
```

If you now create the exe, execute it and take a look at your temp folder (the one where flask looks for templates) you will see that the templates where added there. Now flask is able to find them and everything works like a charme. I did the same for my static files(css and js).

Nonetheless this feels like a workaround. I could imagine that a configuration to tell flask to look somewhere else for the templates(i.e. change the searchpath) would be more elegant. Also it might be possible to add the templates as data or sth. similar when creating the executable using pyinstaller. However I did not manage to achieve either of the two. I hope this fixes the problem for you aswell.